# iPhone Memory Stick Windows Formatting (populating!) Q

Tags: usb, fat32, exfat

**SUMMARY:** Cannot copy more than 32GB of files to a 128GB memory stick formatted under FAT32 or exFAT despite the fact that I can format the stick and ChkDsk is showing the correct results after formatting (and also when less than 32GB of files are on the stick). I cannot use NTFS because this stick is designed to transfer files to an iPhone and the app will not handle NTFS. See below for details.

**DETAILS:**

I have a 128GB memory stick which is designed to quickly transfer files between a computer and an iPhone. One end is a USB and the other plugs into the iPhone's lightning port. This particular type is extremely common and looks like a "T" when you unfold it (Amazon link: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07SB12JHG](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07SB12JHG) ).

While this stick is not especially fast when I copy Windows data to it, the transfer rate to my iPhone is much better than the wireless alternatives.

Normally I'd format a large memory stick or USB drive in NTFS, but the app used to transfer files to my iPhone ("CooDisk") will only handle exFAT and FAT32. I've tried both. For exFAT formatting, I've tried both Windows 7 and 10, and for FAT32 I used a free product from RidgeCrop consulting (I can give you the link if you want).

As with all USB storage devices, my stick is formatted as a single active partition.

I do not have a problem formatting. After formatting, ChkDsk seems happy with both FAT32 and exFAT. The CooDisk app works fine with either. After formatting, all the space is ostensibly available for files.

My problem arises when populating the stick with files.

Whenever I get beyond 32GB in total space, I have various problems. Either the copy will fail, or ChkDsk will fail. (After running ChkDsk in 'fix' mode, every file created beyond the 32GB limit will be clobbered.) Interestingly, when I use the DOS copy command with "/v" (verify) it will flag an error for files beyond the 32GB limit, although DOS XCopy with "/v" keeps on going. GUI methods also die at 32GB.

Out of sheer desperation, I wrote a script that uses GNU's cp for Windows. Now I can copy more than 32GB of files and ChkDsk flags no errors. *However* files beyond the 32GB limit end up being filled with binary zeros despite the fact that they appear as they should in a directory or Windows file explorer listing. (Weird, isn't it?)

I have also tried various allocation unit sizes from 4K all the way up to 64K and attempted this with three different Windows OSs (XP, Win7, and Win10).

Let me emphasize: there is no problem with the first 32GB of files copied to the stick regardless of: whether I use exFAT or FAT32; my method of copying; and my choice of AU size.

Finally, there is nothing in these directories that would bother a FAT32 or exFAT system: (a) file and directory names are short (well under 100 characters); (b) directory nesting is minimal (no more than 5 levels); (c) files are small (nothing close to a GB); and directories have relatively few files (nowhere close to 200, for those of you who recall the old FAT limit of 512 files per directory :)

The *only* platform I haven't yet tried is using an aging MacBook that someone gave to me. I'm not terribly good with Macs, but I would rather not be dependent on it (it's 13 years old, although MacBooks are built like tanks).

Also, is it possible that FAT32 and exFAT don't allow more than 32GB on an active partition (I can find no such limitation documented anywhere, in fact in my experience USB storage devices are always bootable - as was the original version of my stick)?

Any ideas??

Comment: Wrong site, I'm afraid. You're looking for [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. You can find more information about this site in the [help].

Comment: General computer related question, nothing to do with coding.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Maybe a mod can clobber this thread. I'll try the su site.